# Solve $\log_2 (1+\frac{1}{x-1})<1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I don't get how my teacher got two different equations out of the one. One is $> 0$ and the other one is $<2$. Be detailed please.

Comment: Do you mean $\operatorname{log}_2(1+\frac{1}{x-1})<1$?

Comment: What are the two equations you speak of?

Comment: Yes, I can't type it on my iphone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your inequation is
$$
\log_2\left(1+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)<1
$$
then it is equivalent to the system of inequations
\begin{cases}
1+\dfrac{1}{x-1}<2\\[2ex]
1+\dfrac{1}{x-1}>0
\end{cases}
because $2>1$ and so the exponential with base $2$ is increasing. The first is obtained by removing the logarithm, the second because you need to ensure the logarithm exists.

Comment: Why u ensure with greater than zero?

Comment: @user139024 Because $\log_2 t$ is defined only for $t>0$. It's similar to square roots: if you have $\sqrt{t}$ in your expression, you need to ensure $t\ge 0$. Here $t$ stands for any expression.

Comment: Ok, so I have to do this with any log equations

Comment: @user139024 Yes, you have.